Xero custom integration app - node sdk requests failing with 403
I'm trying to set up a custom integration for my Xero organisation account, and I'm busy building it with the Demo Company. We have purchased a subscription for the actual organisation which will be used when the code goes to production.
I'm trying to set up my first API function, which is through the xero-node SDK.
I'm correctly authenticating using my client id and secret, which returns an access token. I then use this access token to make the API request, and i set the access token to my xero client in my code so that i can make the requests through the SDK.
When i try to make a call to xero.accountingAPI.getContacts, i get a 403 error.
I've double checked my scopes and they are fine, my access token decoded includes the accounting.contacts scope so that shouldn't be the issue.
I've read a lot about the xero-tenant-id header, but when i run xero.updateTenants and then print out the list of tenants, them, there is no tenant in the list, it is empty. I'm a bit confused though, my understanding is that there shouldn't be a need for a tenant-id because it is a custom integration, specifically for my own organisation, and so it shouldn't be required.

If the tenant ID is required, can anyone please point me in the right direction of where I get the tenant ID and how i set it in the xero client in my code?

If it's not required, could you please provide some guidance as to what else could be wrong with my set up?


I've included my code below which kicks off when I call the generateClientInXero function, and the error code below that.
A comment - the console.log(xero.tenants) prints a blank array ([])
Thanks!

const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: process.env.XERO_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.XERO_CLIENT_SECRET,
  grantType: "client_credentials",
  scopes: "accounting.transactions accounting.settings accounting.contacts accounting.settings.read".split(" "),
});

const generateClientInXero = async (company) => {
  try {
    // await generateConsentUrl();

    // Obtain access token
    const tokenSet = await getAccessToken();
    console.log("back with access token", tokenSet);
    // const xero_scopes = ;

    // Set the token in Xero client
    xero.setTokenSet(tokenSet);
    xero.updateTenants();
    console.log(xero.tenants);
    // // Setup client and contacts in Xero
    const clientContactID = await setupClientInXero(company);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const getClientCredentialsToken = async () => {
  const url = "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token";
  const client_id = process.env.XERO_CLIENT_ID;
  const client_secret = process.env.XERO_CLIENT_SECRET;
  const xero_scopes = "accounting.transactions accounting.settings accounting.contacts accounting.settings.read"; // Assuming xero_scopes is defined somewhere

  // Encode client_id and client_secret to Base64
  const credentials = Buffer.from(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`).toString("base64");

  // Request body parameters
  const data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
  data.append("scope", "accounting.contacts accounting.transactions accounting.settings accounting.settings.read");

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error obtaining access token:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    throw new Error("Failed to obtain access token");
  }
};
const storeAccessToken = async (accessToken) => {
  const tokenDocRef = firestore.collection("xeroTokens").doc("tokenSet");
  await tokenDocRef.set({
    ...accessToken,
    updatedAt: DateTime.now().toISO(),
  });
};

const loadAccessToken = async () => {
  const tokenDocRef = firestore.collection("xeroTokens").doc("tokenSet");
  const tokenDoc = await tokenDocRef.get();

  if (tokenDoc.exists) {
    const tokenData = tokenDoc.data();
    console.log("Token exists");

    // const currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Current time in milliseconds
    // const expiresAt = tokenData.expiresAt || 0; // Ensure expiresAt is defined

    // if (expiresAt < currentTimestamp) {
    //   console.log("TOKEN EXPIRED - should get new one now");
    //   throw new Error("Xero access token has expired. Please re-authenticate.");
    // }

    return tokenData;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Xero access token not found. Please authenticate first.");
  }
};

const getAccessToken = async () => {
  let accessToken;
  try {
    accessToken = await loadAccessToken();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR IN GET ACCESS TOKEN: ", error);
    accessToken = await getClientCredentialsToken();
    await storeAccessToken(accessToken);
  }
  return accessToken;
};


Error:
{
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 403,
    "body": {
      "Type": null,
      "Title": "Forbidden",
      "Status": 403,
      "Detail": "AuthenticationUnsuccessful",
      "Instance": "43e09fc9-ea0f-4679-b1d5-c907777bacf0",
      "Extensions": {}
    },
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "content-length": "150",
      "server": "nginx",
      "xero-correlation-id": "43e01324-ea0f-4679-b1d5-c912313132",
      "x-appminlimit-remaining": "9998",
      "expires": "Fri, 28 Jun 2024 13:33:19 GMT",
      "cache-control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "date": "Fri, 28 Jun 2024 13:33:19 GMT",
      "connection": "close",
      "x-client-tls-ver": "tls1.3",
      "set-cookie": "ak_bmsc=xxxxxxxxxx....; Domain=.xero.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 28 Jun 2024 15:33:19 GMT; Max-Age=7200"
    },
    "request": {
      "url": { "protocol": "https:", "port": 443, "host": "api.xero.com", "path": "/api.xro/2.0/Contacts" },
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "user-agent": "xero-node-7.0.0",
        "xero-tenant-id": "[object Object]",
        "authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx....",
        "content-length": "2",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
        "host": "api.xero.com"
      },
      "method": "GET"
    }
  },
  "body": {
    "Type": null,
    "Title": "Forbidden",
    "Status": 403,
    "Detail": "AuthenticationUnsuccessful",
    "Instance": "43e09fc9-ea0f-4679-b1d5-c912313132",
    "Extensions": {}
  }
}



This question is similar to: Cannot authenticate with xero-node integration. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JeremyFiel I don't think it's ever a good idea to reference a 7 year old question lol, which is indeed different by the nature of the auth mechanism used. Custom connections are a new feature available in Xero.

Although the tenant id is not required, the custom connection SDKs were generated from the same open API spec as the standard codeflow and so expect a tenant id header.
You can pass the tenant id as an empty string.
See this link for clarification

Thank you Sally! This is interesting and thanks for spotting it in the docs. I actually managed to get my tenant ID through the dev console, will post a separate answer about that.

As an alternative to Sally's response, here's the way that I solved it.
I found the tenantID through the API explorer window as in the screenshot below. I've now made that an environment variable which is added to each header of the requests.
I've left the actual xero-tenant-id out for security reasons, but if you go the 'explorer' tab under the developer console, and expand the 'show auto-generated headers' section, it will show you the xero-tenant-id that the custom connection is authenticated for, under the Authentication header.

